# How do I make android studio recognize my device as an android device?

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't get my apps to run on my device via USB debugging. I have developer mode enabled on my phone, and I have usb debugging enabled as well. The issue is that Android studio recognizes my android devices under  "Found 15 devices not recognized as android devices", but does not allow me to debug through it. How do I make android studio realize that my device is in fact android.

In particular, I'm using a redmi 6 on a windows 7 laptop. Does the issue have something to do with the redmi 6 using the modified MIUI?

Comment: You need to install the correct adb adapter of your mobile device

Comment: In your phone, when you scroll down does it say "transfer files" or "just charging"?

Comment: Transfer Files; Where can I install the adapter? Do I do this on my phone or computer?

Comment: install adapter on the computer

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.xiaomidriversdownload.com/xiaomi-usb-drivers-official/)